# How can I install ruby on rails with rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

I've been searching around on how to install it through the terminal on my mac. I'm using snow leopard. 
When I use the command: rvm install 1.9.3
I've also followed the other procedures that led me up to this to install, right now the current version is 1.8.3

> Error running './configure --prefix="/Users/jose/.rvm/usr" ', please read /Users/jose/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/configure.log

Then it mentions something about xcode and autoreconf was not found in the PATH.

> Error running 'patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f <"/Users/jose/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/xcode-debugopt-fix-e34840.diff"',please read /Users/jose/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/patch.apply.xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.log
>   rvm requires autoreconf to install the selected ruby interpreter however autoreconf was not found in the PATH

I been trying for awhile now, and found out i need to have Xcode for snow leopard which I cannot find. So my last option will be to upgrade to lion but I don't know about upgrading. Kind of scared to upgrade and everything becomes buggy.

> Rails 2.3.5
>   Jose-Gomezs-MacBook-Pro:~ josegomez$ ruby -v
>   ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
>   Jose-Gomezs-MacBook-Pro:~ josegomez$ gem -v
>   1.8.15
>   Jose-Gomezs-MacBook-Pro:~ josegomez$ rvm -v
>
> rvm 1.11.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis > [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

Comment: Just found a Blog-Post. Maybe this will help you: http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-install-rvm-and-rails-3-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: The link is now http://c.kat.pe/post/how-to-install-rvm-and-rails-3-on-snow-leopard/ (Not too helpful for Mac OS X Mavericks users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close it off, I found out I had to push back my date on my mac to sometime before January 2012 and install xcode. After installation you can set the time back to normal and you should be good to go. But I got a copy of xcode from my instructor which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 6):

Install brew, then:

```
brew install automake
```

Will add autoreconf to your path.

1.9.3 now works with the LLVM compiler in XCode 4.3 so you shouldn't have any issues installing the latest version from the App Store.

I rebuilt my mac last night and everything was pretty stock standard. RVM, Brew, XCode from the App Store, Command Line Tools from XCode, autoreconf from brew, 1.9.3-p125 from rvm.

Comment: although it works for you there is no guarantee it will work for others, only `1.9.3-head` is fully LLVM ready, but it's repeated all the time starting from 1.9.3-p0, compiling with gcc-4.2 (non LLVM) is better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For getting patch application problems - use `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`.

For installing ruby 1.8.7 you need GCC 4.2 like (gcc-4.2 program) not an LLVM based compiler (like clang), the easiest way to get it is osx-gcc-installer, you could also install Xcode 4.1 - but this is harder.

Please take a note that `1.9.3-p125` is not fully ready for clang, you still are better with `gcc-4.2` form `osx-gcc-installer` / `Xcode 4.1`

Answer (score 0):

I did it on my Mac and I remember changing some settings in my .bash_profile. Here is a link I followed to do it. Hope it works for you as well.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/

Comment: I'm following the tutorial as well but it's the xcode software I need to successfully install ruby. I cant seem to find the right copy of it for my mac version

Comment: Didnt you get a disc from Apple when you purchased your MAC ? That install disc has XCode needed for RVM.

Answer (score 0):

Signing up for a free developer account with Apple will give you access to Xcode for Snow Leopard. Once you install Xcode and the included Developer Tools, you'll be all set to install Ruby on Rails with RVM.

Comment: I have signed up but when I search for xcode for snow leopard nothing shows the latest version of xcode appears. And I found xcode version 3.2.6 and when I run the installer i get an error at the end.

Comment: It seems they've redesigned the site a bit since I last visited. You can find the Xcode for Snow Leopard by Viewing All Downloads and then searching for the version you want. What error are you getting when you try to install it?

Answer (score 0):

only tittle related:

```
bash -s stable --rails < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

you can get more details here: https://gist.github.com/2246595 - this will enter guide mode that helps to get it app and running

Answer (score 0):

Try this script by ThoughtBot to automatically configure your system: 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop

It does a.lot and generally will take a Lion system, get gcc installed, and get rvm and finally rails. highly recommend.